# How to read and write CSV with async data?

Tags: node.js, csv, async-await

I'm trying to read a CSV, enrich the data with some external API and then write a new CSV.

My issue is to wait until ALL the calls to the API has been completed before writing the CSV.
So far, I write every line but the last one - the end event trigger "too soon", it don't wait for my last call to finish.

Here is what I did:

```
const stream = await fs
  .createReadStream('./foo.csv')
  .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',', from_line: 2 }))
  .on('data', async function (row) {
    try {
      stream.pause()
      const foo1 = row[0]
      const foo2 = await externalAPI(row[1])
      const newRow = [foo1, foo2]
      data.push(newRow)
    } finally {
      stream.resume()
    }
  })
  .on('end', function () {
     stringify(data, (err, output) => {
         fs.writeFileSync('demoA.csv', output)
     })

  })
  .on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read csv file completely, call the external api then write output to a new csv file.

```js
const rows = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const data = [];
  fs
  .createReadStream('./foo.csv')
  .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',', from_line: 2 }))
  .on('data', (row) => data.push(row)) // collect row
  .on('end', () => resolve(data)) // return data
  .on('error', (error) => reject(error))
});

const newRows = [];
for (const [col0, col1] of rows) {
  const newCol = await externalAPI(col1); // wait for external api call
  newRows.push([col0, newCol]);
}

stringify(newRows, (err, output) => {
  fs.writeFileSync('demoA.csv', output)
});
```